# How to Run clamd service in clamav using cronjob

Tags: java, spring, sandbox, antivirus, clamav

I recently installed clamav antivirus in sandbox environment. I am scanning `.xfa` file using an API(java spring boot) deployed to same sandbox env.

1. For virus signature database I prepared shell scrip to run freshclam command after every 48 hours. Its working fine.
2. Before sending any file from my API to clamav I have to manually run clamd service in sandbox env using cmd. Then it remains active for 24 hours (not sure about exact timings)
   Question : - how can I automate clamd service. Is there any way to run from code API. I don't want to run it manually everytime before scanning the file.

Question : - how can i automate clamd service. Is there any way to run from code API. I dont want to run it manually everytime before scanning the file.